# Magento get all parent ids

Tags: php, magento, csv, categories

I am having some troubles getting all parent id's from a category id.
Imagine this category tree:

```
2
 - 5
   - 8
 - 6
   - 9
   - 12
     - 20
```

Now, lets say I want all parent id's of '12'. That would be 2,6,12.
I think you know what i'm doing here. I am making the 'category_ids' field for importing products.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
```

Each category has a field called `path` that contains the ids of the parents and current category.

```
$path = $category->getPath();
```

This should return something like this `1/2/6/12`.
All you need to do is to split this string by `/` and remove the first element. That one is the id for 'root of all roots'.

```
$ids = explode('/', $path);
unset($ids[0]);
```

Now you should have what you are looking for in `$ids`

Answer (score 1):

$category->getPathIds(); is easier